# Recommend a free Java library to construct a tree and get path between leaf nodes?

Tags: java, tree

Can you please recommend a Java library for creating trees? I am looking for a library that will compute various paths between leaf nodes, report the number of leaf nodes the tree has, and other utility methods.

Comment: How about javax.swing.tree.TreeModel?

Comment: @assylias I think the OP is referring to the Tree data structure, not the GUI meaning.

Comment: @Jonathan TreeModel happens to be in the swing package, but it is a tree data structure and does not contain any GUI-related code (AFAIK). It also has a default implementation (DefaultTreeModel). Now you can use a TreeModel as the model of a JTree which is a GUI representation of the TreeModel but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jgrapht](http://jgrapht.org/).  From the webpage:

> JGraphT is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms. JGraphT supports various types of graphs including:
>
> - directed and undirected graphs.
> - graphs with weighted / unweighted / labeled or any user-defined edges.
> - various edge multiplicity options, including: simple-graphs, multigraphs, pseudographs.
> - unmodifiable graphs - allow modules to provide "read-only" access to internal graphs.
> - listenable graphs - allow external listeners to track modification events.
> - subgraphs graphs that are auto-updating subgraph views on other graphs.
> - all compositions of above graphs.
>
> Although powerful, JGraphT is designed to be simple and type-safe (via Java generics). For example, graph vertices can be of any objects. You can create graphs based on: Strings, URLs, XML documents, etc; you can even create graphs of graphs!

Other [SO users report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727788/java-library-for-trees-similar-to-jgrapht-for-graphs) success with [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).  My careful 30 second review of their API suggests that you should start [HERE](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Tree.html).

Comment: I'll note that I just now learned about SO's "LMGTFY" ban. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: Someone else likes "Jung" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727788/java-library-for-trees-similar-to-jgrapht-for-graphs